# Debugging Visual Basic (VB6) in Windows 10 (MTS Transaction Mode)

Tags: transactions, com, vb6, windows-10

We've noticed that debugging VB6 applications in Windows 10 fail when MTSTransactionMode is set to an option that is a transaction. i.e: Anything other than No transaction.

The error message is:

> TNS Could not be initialized

Comment: It seems this is coming from Oracle right? What's the ORA error number?

Comment: Not sure on the error number: Exact error is : Data provider could not be initialized

Answer (score 0):

In the project, select the class and display the properties window. MTSTransactionMode will be shown. Set them all to 0 - NotAnMTSObject, if you are not using MTS.